# What could be preventing my browser from finding a DNS address?

Tags: networking, dns

I'm specifically trying to reach `lvh.me` but for some reason I get

> lvh.me’s server DNS address could not be found.

I verified with some other people that it worked for them and I can connect to it when I'm on a VPN, but for some reason it can't get to it otherwise.

What specific entities have the ability to prevent me from reaching a specific url? I want to keep this question more general so that it can help other users.

Note: `lvh.me` is a special website in that it resolves to `127.0.0.1` so if you're not running anything locally, you will recieve a different error like

> lvh.me refused to connect.

Comment: OS?  Network configuration? Does it work for others using the same nameserver [ eg on your LAN?]

Comment: Doesn't work on my PC plugged into the modem and doesn't work on my Wifi. But it does work when I switch to an external wifi (ex. xfinitywifi)

Comment: So then there is probably a caching issue or misconfiguration on your modem (which I assume is a router).